# How to iterate over objects/arrays using the same function (without forEach)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an academic assignment that requires my function to iterate over a collection. I am basically learning how the forEach works, so I cannot use that. The collection could be an array or an object. I know how to do both separately, but how do I make the existing function cope with whatever collection is passed to it?
So far, this is what I have for the array portion:

```
function(myCollection, myIterFunc){
for (var i = 0; i< myCollection.length; i++){
    myIterFunc(myCollection[i], i, myCollection);
}
};
```

Comment: Use `myCollection instanceof Array` to tell if the argument is an array or object. If it's an array you use your existing loop, if it's an object use `for (i in myCollection)`

Comment: Can you use object.keys?

Comment: if (Array.isArray(myCollection)){for loop}
else {for in loop}

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks a lot, I had not done much with instanceof before so this is a great help.

Comment: @Barmar , could you write that as an answer so OP can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: @Owen Your answer looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the isArray method.

```
function(myCollection, myIterFunc){
    if (Array.isArray(myCollection)){
        for (var i = 0; i< myCollection.length; i++){
            myIterFunc(myCollection[i], i, myCollection);
        }
    } else {
        for (var key in myCollection){
            if (myCollection.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                myIterFunc(myCollection[key], key, myCollection);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up with something similar, but I went the instanceof Array route, which works great.

Comment: No worries. I found the following site which suggests myCollection.constructor === Array to be the fastest method. https://jsperf.com/instanceof-array-vs-array-isarray

Comment: Owen that depends a great deal on the browser. iOS browser found the instanceof method to be the fastest.

Comment: The *Array* loop should have an own property test too, since it may be sparse and the function probably should only be called on members that exist (per *forEach*).

Comment: @Tobias—the sole reason for an *isArray* method in ES5 is that other methods, such as checking the constructor or using *instanceof*, are unreliable.

Comment: To be honest, neither did I.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var str = 'one, two, three';
var ob = {
  item_1: 'one',
  item_2: 'two',
  item_3: 'three'
};
var ary = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

var myRuggedLittleIterator = function(col){
  if(typeof col !== 'object'){return;} 
  var colKeys = Object.keys(col);
  for (var i = 0; i < colKeys.length; i++){
    console.log(col[colKeys[i]]);
  }
};

myRuggedLittleIterator(str);
myRuggedLittleIterator(ob);
myRuggedLittleIterator(ary);
```

Comment: I think he's saying he needs to access the list of properties without using the for in syntax.

Comment: yep, I got it now -- takes some time some times.

Comment: Congrats you've just completed some homework!    I didn't know about object.keys until I saw this question.

Answer (score -1):

Then do some academic research by looking at [jQuery's source code for it's `each` method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L270) (don't plagiarize just take some inspiration)

Inside your method, you will always have to check if you're iterating over an object or array, because the means of iterating over these structures are different.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that is available to look at but I just find asking questions here helps me understand things a lot better.